# Entity Framework fails to update record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Server table in Entity Framework ComputerLab with two foreign keys named `LabId`, `ComputerId` and another key named `Entrance`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputerLabs] 
(
    [LabId]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [ComputerId] INT      NOT NULL,
    [Entrance]   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Exit]       DATETIME NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputerLabs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ComputerId] ASC, [LabId] ASC, [Entrance] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ComputerLabs_Lab] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([LabId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lab] ([LabId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ComputerLabs_Computer] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ComputerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Computer] ([ComputerId])
);
```

Mapping : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVNIG.png)

and a function that updates the record (that match the given `computerId, labId` and that have no exit value):

```
public void RemoveComputerFromLab(int compId, int labId)
{
    var cList = db.ComputerLabs.Where(e => !e.Exit.HasValue && e.LabId.Equals(labId)).ToList();

    if (cList.Count > 0)
    {
        ComputerLab cL = cList.First();
        cL.Exit = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(cL).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        /* also tried:
        ComputerLab cL = cList.First();
        db.ComputerLabs.Attach(cL);
        cL.Exit = DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();
        */
    }
}
```

`SaveChanges()` throws the exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

but there is no other process that could modify this entity.

The same exception happens when I'm trying to delete the record:

```
private void DeleteComputerLab(int compId, int labId, DateTime entrance)
{
    var entity = db.ComputerLabs.Find(labId, compId, entrance);

    lab.ComputerLabs.Remove(entity);
    //db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted; -not working either
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've tested your code - it works for me fine. One note - there's no need to set `State` property to `Modified` (in `RemoveComputerFromLab`). Here's the [code](https://pastebin.com/swy7E65i) I used.

Comment: Please show how you mapped `ComputerLabs` to the entity class. I bet that EF doesn't know about the composite primary key.

Comment: @GertArnold I added the image of the mapping to the post, is that the mapping you meant?